# rails 4, dry custom wrappers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I am wondering how I can make it more easy with repeated codes. Like in all modelpages I use the same type of code to show all attribute values. Everytime I have to type the same pieces:

```
%label.col-sm-3.control-label
    = :attribute
.col-sm-9
    = @attribute.value
```

I tried to do something with helpers, but can't get anything working. I was trying to make something (DRY) like:

```
= form_row, :attribute, @attribute.value
```

That should generate the complete set including the css etc.

Comment: Is `form_row` the name of your helper?  You shouldn't have a comma between the method name and the first argument.  Also, what you probably really want is a partial.

Comment: To avoid creating labels each time, you can use https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-inputs it is easy to create your custom input with label.

Comment: @depquid: form_row is indeed the name of the helper

Comment: @mixan946: The thing is that I am not using simple_form. I would like to have just a screen with "static" text and no inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helper should look like

```
def form_row(name, value)
  result = label_tag "", name, class: "col-sm-3 control-label"
  result << content_tag(:div, value, class: "col-sm-9")    
end
```

And then in your view call this method

```
= form_row :attribute, @attribute.value
```